# How can I preview iPhone photos in Nautilus file manager?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, iphone, thumbnails, photo-management

I've selected the Nautilus setting to always show thumbnails and it works when browsing most directories containing images with Nautilus, but it doesn't work for my iPhone directory.

How can I browse my iPhone images in Nautilus?

[image: no thumbnails]